# How to call this method into my other file?

Tags: java

I want to be able to call the Introduction.Intro() method into my main file code, but it tells me I am unable to call a non-static method intro from a static context. Since I am still fairly new to coding I'm not entirely sure what the problem is. I've added my codes down below. I've tried countless online methods but sadly none have seemed to work.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Start extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    private JFrame Main;
    private JPanel PanelA, PanelB, PanelC;
    private JLabel Text, ImageL;
    private JButton Button;
    private ImageIcon Image;
    
    public Start ()
    {
        //Button
        Button = new JButton("Start");
        Button.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        
        //Text
        Text = new JLabel("Welcome To The Game"); //ADD NAME OF THE GAME
        
        //Image
        Image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("download.jfif")); //ADD THE IMAGE FOR WELCOME
        ImageL = new JLabel(Image);
        
        //Top Panel (PanelA) - Image
        PanelA = new JPanel();
        PanelA.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0,200,150,200));
        PanelA.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        PanelA.add(ImageL);
        
        //Middle Panel (PanelB) - Text
        PanelB = new JPanel();
        PanelB.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(50,200,10,200));
        PanelB.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        PanelB.add(Text);
        
        //Bottom Panel (PanelC) - Buttons
        PanelC = new JPanel();
        PanelC.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0,200,20,200));
        PanelC.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));  
        PanelC.add(Button);
        
        //Main Frame
        Main = new JFrame ();
        Main.add(PanelA, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        Main.add(PanelB, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        Main.add(PanelC, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        Main.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Main.setTitle("GAME TITLE"); //ADD THIS LATER
        Main.pack();
        Main.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
    {
        
    }
    
    public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener 
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            if(e.getSource() == Button)
            {
                Introduction.Intro1();    //THESE LINE RIGHT HERE
                return null;              //THESE LINE RIGHT HERE
            }
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Start();
    }
}
```

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Introduction 
{ 
    private JFrame Main;
    private JPanel PanelD;
    private JLabel Text, ImageL;
    private JButton Button;
    private ImageIcon Image;
        
    public void Intro()
    {
        Image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("guy.jfif"));
        ImageL = new JLabel(Image);
        
        PanelD = new JPanel();
        PanelD.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0,100,10,100));
        PanelD.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        PanelD.add(ImageL);
        
        PanelD.setVisible(true);
        Main.add(PanelD, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }
}
```

EDIT: So I made another method in the Introduction class where I added this line of code, it managed to fix the error, however, the panel isn't being saved and my JFrame is outputting blank.

```
public static JFrame Intro1()
{
    Introduction M = new Introduction();
    return M;
}
```

Comment: Do you know what static means?

Comment: Introduction.Info references instance variables, therefore you need to create an instance to do this.

Comment: @NomadMaker do you happen to know how I would be able to do that?

Comment: ``Introduction intro = new Introduction(); intro.Info();`` You need to pay more attention to your java book.

Comment: @NomadMaker I kinda dont have a java book just learning from trial and error and online videos really. Sorry

Comment: There are a lot of online tutorials. They are much better than videos for learning (for most people). You should learn more about the basics. For one thing, java naming conventions have variables and methods start with lower case letters.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to initialize the Introduction class in main method of Start class, You can add belo code in main method after **Start()**

```
Introduction M = new Introduction();
```

You main method becomes :

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Start();
        Introduction M = new Introduction();
        m.Intro
    }
```

Looking at this set of code, It looks like there is incompatible issue, as you have declare JFrame as return type, while you are returning instance of Introduction.

```
public static JFrame Intro1()
{
    Introduction M = new Introduction();
    return M;
}
```